# Added songs does not appear

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-830, groove

Phone: Nokia Lumia 830
OS: Windows 10 Mobile
Used: Explorer

When I add songs in my music folder (where every other song is) it does not appear in Groove application.

Problem didn't occurred in WP 8

{Removable Storage Devices\Kedova lumia v2\Phone\Music}

Please help.

Comment: How are you adding songs to the folder? Are you doing this by removing the SD card, adding using another device, and replacing the card? Are you doing it by using Windows Explorer and copying to the phone via USB? Are you copying using Windows Media Player? or something else?

Comment: I am using an usb device and I am copying files through windows explorer.

I am **not** using an SD card. 

I just copy (mp3) files to the folder where every other song is, I open groove music. 

I tried: 

 - Waiting a bit
 - Turned all filters off
 - Searched for the track by name, interpret, file name

Comment: Odd. that sounds like the same method I use, and that works for me no problem

Comment: Do you synchronize it somehow ?

Comment: I just tried to remove all the songs. The list remained the same, but all the songs are unplayable.

Comment: Are the songs copyrighted? Drm? I've had mp3's that didn't show up i think because of some DRM.